# Parse Multi List with Dictionaries

Tags: python

I have the following list from which I wan't to extract only the 5 string numeric values.

```
x = [{'metric': {}, 
      'values': [[a, '100'], 
                 [b, '99.98'], 
                 [c, '89.7654'], 
                 [d, '87.98'], 
                 [e, '100']
                 ]
     }
    ]
```

I have managed to do so with the following code but I'm sure there is a more Pythonesque method of doing so.

```
for result in x:
for m in result['values']:
    print(m[1])
```

Your help would be most appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Other than your indentation being off I don't see anything unpythonic about your solution.  I  take it x is more than 1 element long?

Comment: That's what I would do, assuming the data structure is locked in. You could use operator.itemgetter, but that seems gratuitous.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the values as a list, you could use a comprehension:

```
>>> a, b, c, d, e = "abcde"
>>> x = [{'metric': {},
...       'values': [[a, '100'],
...                  [b, '99.98'],
...                  [c, '89.7654'],
...                  [d, '87.98'],
...                  [e, '100']
...                  ]
...      }
...     ]
>>>
>>> [v[1] for d in x for v in d['values']]
['100', '99.98', '89.7654', '87.98', '100']
```

Comment: This is good because you have a value to return, thus making it possible to put it in a function and write unit tests for the function. After that, printing it is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

i think that your code is good; in my opinion, sometimes, list and dictionary comprehensions makes your code more confuse than if you did it the traditional way.

PS: i don't mean you shouldn't use list/dictionary comprehensions

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about 'most' pythonic, there are a lot of ways to do it. I would say either a list comprehension (if you want to return the list of values) or iterating (if you want to do other things with them at the same time) are the most common.

Your data is a little confusing -- you seem to have a list with one entry: a dictionary. Inside that dictionary are two entries (metric - an empty dictionary, and values - a list of lists). Is that what you really wanted?

Iteration (but no need to take two passes - since there's only one element in x, just refer to it directly instead of your outer loop):

```
For value in x[0]['values']:
    print(value[1])
```

Or, if you want to just return the list (rather than printing it), a list comprehension like Samwise's above works well.